# Why isn't the Jordan Curve Theorem axiomatic?

Tags: general-topology, axioms, foundations

> In topology, a Jordan curve is a non-self-intersecting continuous loop in the plane, and another name for a Jordan curve is a plane simple closed curve. The Jordan curve theorem asserts that every Jordan curve divides the plane into an "interior" region bounded by the curve and an "exterior" region containing all of the nearby and far away exterior points, so that every continuous path connecting a point of one region to a point of the other intersects with that loop somewhere. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem))

That a continuous closed non-self-intersecting loop would divide a normal euclidean plane into two regions which can be joined only by a path crossing the loop would have been axiomatic, or so I would have thought. It is inherent in the idea of a closed non-intersecting curve that it defines an inside and an outside.

Are the difficulties in proving the theorem present in a simple euclidean plane, or only when it is applied to non-euclidean geometries or higher dimensions?

Comment: The difficulties are present in the Euclidean plane, but also in the projective plane and the hyperbolic plane, and in fact on any plane, as the exact geometry of the plane is of little consequence. Only the topology matters (including the global topology, as the theorem is clearly false on a torus). And the difficulty in proving the theorem lies in how ugly a function $S^1\to \Bbb R^2$ can really be, and still be continuous and injective (we usually think about piecewise smooth functions when we picture them, possibly with a finite number of anomalies).

Comment: The problem is that continuous paths can differ strongly from intuition. For example (although this is self intersecting), there are space filling curves.

Comment: @AreaMan I haven't ever seen a closed space filling curve, though I expect there would be some. Do you know of any examples.

Comment: @curiousdannii There aren't any, since the image of a continuous function from $S^1$ (which is one way to view a closed curve) must be compact. It would also be difficult to make it injective.

Comment: @Arthur That's not a problem. I'm talking about filing a closed square - "space" was kind of ambiguous, I meant it in dimensiony kind of way. And yes, just take any continuous surjection $ \gamma: [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$, then extend this to a path on $[0,2]$ by on $[1,2]$ going from $\gamma(1)$ to $\gamma(0)$.

Comment: Is "closed" equivalent to "continuous"? If they are not the same, and the JCT only refers to continuous curves not closed curves then I'd understand its difficulty more.

Comment: The JCT refers to ["Jordan curves"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanCurve.html), which are curves whose images are homeomorphic to the circle.

Comment: When you are talking about a map between topological spaces closed and continuous are different properties that don't generally imply each other. When you are talking about a "closed" curve, you generally don't mean that the map is closed, but that the endpoint is the same as the start point. However, once you have a continuous map from the circle into a Hausdorff space (e.g. the plane) it is automatically a closed map.

Comment: Just to wrap up this discussion of the space filling curve, since I'm not sure if I am miscommunicating or misleading the OP: Suppose we have a map $\gamma : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$, which is continuous and surjective. Then it is impossible that $\gamma$ is injective, for $\gamma$ is automatically closed (the domain being compact), it would follow that $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism. It is a good exercise to show that this is a contradiction There is no way to produce a Jordan curve this way - the example of space filling curves is just to emphasize the weirdness of continuous maps.

Comment: It's not just a property of a curve, but a property of a curve in a plane.

Comment: @BCLC: Don't editorialise old posts. If you have a significant edit to make, that's one thing; but a small change of language that "could work here" is not a good edit. If you're hunting for a badge, find content that really needs editing.

Answer (score 8):

You write "it is inherent in the idea of a closed non-intersecting curve that it defines an inside and an outside".

Mathematics makes progress by questioning what seems to be inherent. For example, although Euclid included in his axioms the famous parallel postulate, which perhaps seemed inherent at the time, from very early in the history of mathematics people were *not* always willing to accept the parallel postulate as an axiom. There were many (failed) attempts to *prove* the parallel postulate from the other axioms of Euclid. Eventually, after about 2 millennia it was discovered that the parallel postulate was not inherent at all, in fact it is independent of the other axioms, because one can construct the hyperbolic plane which satisfies all of Euclid's axioms except the parallel postulate. From this we can conclude that it *is* good to include the parallel postulate as an axiom of Euclidean geometry.

The problem with simply deciding that an "inherent" property should be an axiom is that it is not good to accept unwarranted assumptions. What if the JCT turned out to be false? What if it turned out that there existed a Jordan curve in the plane whose complement had 3 or more connected components, contrary to the conclusion of the JCT that there are exactly 2 connected components? It's hard to know ahead of time whether that's how things will turn out. If one thought, back in the 19th century, that the JCT is inherent in our understanding of the Euclidean plane, to make progress one should still question that thought.

One may raise a valid question about any seemingly "inherent" property: Is it really always true? Or is there a counterexample?

In the case of the parallel postulate, there exists a counterexample, i.e. a mathematical object satisfying all axioms of Euclidean geometry except for the parallel postulate, namely the hyperbolic plane.

In the case of the JCT, it is always true: the complement of every Jordan curve in the Euclidean plane has 2 connected components (one bounded, one unbounded). Nowadays this theorem is taught in a first year algebraic topology course, requiring a lot of carefully developed topological machinery. From this we can conclude that it is *bad* to include the JCT theorem as an axiom of Euclidean geometry.

**Appendix 1:** I'm beginning to think that you might find the [Kline Sphere Characterization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kline_sphere_characterization) to be interesting and relevant to your question. What that theorem says is this:

- If $X$ is a compact, connected, locally connected metric space with more than one point, if no pair of points separates $X$, but if every simple closed curve separates $X$, then $X$ is a homeomorphic to the 2-sphere.

Here is an immediate corollary:

- If $X$ is a noncompact, connected, locally connected, nonempty metric space, if no single point separates $X$ and no pair of points separates $X$, if every simple closed curve separates $X$, and if every closed subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ separates $X$, then $X$ is homeomorphic to the plane.

So one can conclude that the JCT is indeed inherent in the topological concept of "being homeomorphic to the plane", rather than to the Euclidean concept of "being a Euclidean plane".

**Appendix 2:** Regarding axiom systems, you can think of almost any definition as an axiom system, and sometimes that is enforced by the language. For instance, sometimes you will hear one speak about the definition of a group as the "axioms for a group": a set, with a binary operation satisfying the associative law, and with an identity element satisfying the inverse law. When you study group theory, *every* property of a group should be viewed through the lens of whether it is "inherent" or "not inherent".

As a simple example: is the commutative law an inherent property of groups? Translation: Is every group commutative, or on the other hand do there exist noncommutative groups?

This is just one example, but this frame of mind is a great way to study and learn new mathematics.

Comment: All axioms are tested, and many axiom systems have been replaced. But I don't get the argument of your final paragraph. Axioms can always be proved rather than assumed if you start with a different set of axioms. Why is it bad to include the JCT as an axiom of euclidean geometry just because its topological proof is so involved?

Comment: What is the point of an axiomatic system if you just throw in any axiom you want? Without care, you might create an inconsistent system of axioms (if the axiom you throw in is provably false). Or, you might create a redundant system of axioms (if the axiom you throw in is provably true). What makes a good, well crafted axiom system is that each axiom is independent of the others: there is a model of the others in which the given axiom is true; and there is a model in which it is false. **That** is the reason why the parallel postulate is a good axiom.

Comment: Alright, this level of maths is beyond me. But if I can make an analogy, rather than the axiom of parallel lines which can be evaluated in the ways you outlined, the JCT, the idea that closed curves define insides and outsides, feels more like the definition that a triangle has three sides. That just seems inherent in the idea of "closed", in Euclidean space. And the fact that it doesn't hold in other geometries would have affirmed to me that it's part of what makes Euclidean Euclidean.

Comment: But I guess the fact it isn't just shows it's more complicated than I can understand. Oh well.

Comment: Let me add one or two more things. Regarding the JCT itself, what is relevant is not the geometry of the Euclidean plane but its topology. The fact that the JCT does not hold in other *topologies* is what makes a *topological plane* a *topological plane*. You might find the "Kline sphere characterization" theorem interesting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kline_sphere_characterization. I will add some comments about this to my answer.

Comment: Regarding axioms systems, I've added some comments to my answer to try to encourage you to believe that axiomatic mathematics is not so complicated, it just requires a different frame of mind.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments in no particular order:

- You can have closed non-intersecting curves on the sphere. This will divide the sphere into two halves, but it's not clear which one is the "inside" and which is the "outside." Also, you can have a closed non-intersecting curve in the circle. This doesn't divide the circle in any meaningful way; indeed, such curves will always cover the entire circle. And of course, you can have a closed non-intersecting curve in real $3$-space; this won't disconnect the space.
- Usually we base math on the principles of set theory (or perhaps $\infty$-groupoid theory) or something like that. I don't know of any genuinely successful attempts to found mathematics on geometry. So from this point of view, we can't really choose our axioms of geometry. They're meant to flow from the definitions, and certain basic principles about the universe of sets ($\infty$-groupoids, whatever.)
- It might be possible to *characterize* the plane as the unique topological manifold satisfying the Jordan curve theorem. (And this is a good question btw, +1).

Comment: Funny that you say we don't really have geometric axioms when they were [first conceived of in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom#Early_Greeks) :)

Comment: @curiousdannii, yes, sure. You can *axiomatize* parts of geometry. But you cannot *found* math on geometry, as a far as I know. For example, I cannot see a list of axioms about the Euclidean plane giving rise to Cantor's theory of the transfinite cardinal and ordinal numbers.

Comment: There are axiomatisations of geometry. The most common (modern) one due to Hilbert is detailed by both [Hartshorne](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387986500) and [Greenberg](https://www.amazon.com/Euclidean-Non-Euclidean-Geometries-Development-History/dp/0716799480), and probably many others. I don't read the question as wanting to found mathematics on geometry, just that it was about the axiomatisation of geometry.

Comment: @Arthur, I think you're reading the question incorrectly. Quote: "That a continuous closed non-self-intersecting loop would divide a normal euclidean plane into two regions which can be joined only by a path crossing the loop would have been axiomatic, or so I would have thought. It is inherent in the idea of a closed non-intersecting curve that it defines an inside and an outside." The OP is implicitly subscribing to the classical of an axiom as "a statement that is so evident or well-established, that it is accepted without controversy or question." The only context in which this...

Comment: ... viewpoint on axioms still holds water is foundational mathematics.

Comment: Well, I guess that is true. But then you should talk about what an axiom is, rather than trying to mix ZF into this (which, by the way, doesn't contain only well-established or evident statements either).

Comment: @Arthur, fair point. If I can find the energy, I'll do an edit with these kinds of details. Btw, I never mentioned ZF, which personally I have mixed feelings about.

Comment: I would think those were the "principles of set theory" you mentioned. It is the most common set of axioms on which to base set theory, after all, so I don't think it was a far-fetched assumption. At any rate, I'll stop pestering you about minor details now.

Comment: @Arthur, that's okay, I don't feel pestered. ZF(C) is indeed the most common set of axioms on which to base set-theoretic investigations, but those who are interested in computer-formalization of math are vigorously pursuing the development of alternative, more user-friendly frameworks.

Comment: Forgetting about set theory for a minute, you can indeed found a fair chunk of modern mathematics on geometry: there is a well-developed derivation of the axioms of the real numbers starting with axioms for Euclidean geometry. A good starting place for learning about this is Stillwell's book "Four pillars of geometry".

Comment: @goblin,certainly not everyone interested in computer-formalization is shunning ZF(C) or similar; the Metamath community is fine with it, for instance. But I have to admit you might be right if you said "most of those who are interested..."

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in a very real sense.  If you look at Hilbert's "Foundation of Geometry" you will discover there is a betweenness axiom characterized by a line passing across a triangle.  The triangle acts to select a line segment all of whose points lie between the two points of intersection with the triangle.

That this does not translate to foundational views reflects the emphasis upon arithmetization of mathematics that had been popular at the time foundational studies arose.  Frege, however, had retracted his logicism and proposed that all mathematics is based upon geometry.  In this regard, it is of interest that the sixteen basic Boolean functions relate to one another as a finite affine plane.  You can see the significant pattern leading to this recognition by studying negations and de Morgan conjugations as involutions over the truth tables.  Such facts, however, are irrelevant to those who promote the received view based upon arithmetization and the import of Goedel's theorems.